# Eclipse does not recognize my changes in src folder, throws the same error

Tags: eclipse, websphere-8

I'm having a hard time using eclipse because of the following issue.

It goes like this. I'll code and try to run it. Then, it will throw some errors (of any kind). And so, after I have changed a part of the code, comment out which codes I suspect makes the error, or delete something, I then restart the websphere application server in order to republish my work. Next is to test my work using SoapUI then all of a sudden eclipse throws an error which is the same as before. I've tried to search in here answers to this questions but it involves codes which don't need in my project and also answers that I can't understand well (since I am very new to programming). However, I have found a way to resolve this but it's very inconvenient. To be able for eclipse to detect changes in the src folder, I should restart eclipse after editing my codes then remove my project in the server, start the server and then publish my work in websphere all over again. It solves my problem but I do all of these stuff every now and then even if I only comment out a single line in the code. What I want is to avoid doing this process of resolving the issue since it consumes so much of my time whenever I republish the project in the server.

Can somebody help me with this? Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit strange that you need to restart eclipse. The normal way would be to just re run your application server. 
Try only he 3 second steps you mentioned (remove my project in the server, start the server and then publish my work in websphere) and if that works try again without removing the project. Just restart the servers. 
And let us know if that worked!

Comment: Hello @steliios! That's what I've done before figuring out that I need to restart eclipse. :( It still doesn't see the changes I've made

Comment: maybe this article could help you more:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280675/is-it-possible-to-apply-changes-to-jsf-files-without-republishing

Comment: Noted! I'll check it out immediately and inform you if I have resolved this one. Thank you so much!!

Comment: you have saved me hahaha it worked! thanks so much @stelios !

Comment: glad i could help :)